# Is there a default "dark" theme (i.e. black background)?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, themes

For the majority of its life Android has had a dark UI (color text on black background), then it switched to light background on Android 6.

[Android 7 will feature a "night mode"](http://www.androidcentral.com/night-mode-back-and-we-hope-its-here-stay) which will permit to restore the black background, having the standard UI in reverse colors.

While waiting for it, is there a "dark" theme for Android 6 that would have the same effect?

Comment: Themes are plenty, although the majority of them are available only for custom ROM users.

Comment: I'm not looking for a standard dark theme. I'm looking for the default Android UI (or at least something very similar) on black background.

Comment: @dr01 You can't theme stock Android. Also, this post seems to be off-topic for Android Enthusiasts, as it is asking for software recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the "night mode" promised for Android 7 hasn't been implemented after all, but there's a High Contrast Theme by Samsung for Android 7 that works in a similar way.